# Cannot Download SDK for android studio in Mac OS M1 Chip

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

[[image]](https://i.stack.i[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGn4Q.png)mgur.com/GeDGC.png)

These are the errors i am facing. I have tried downloading sdk command line tools to my local and stored them in the sdk file but i stilll face this error.

Anyone else facing the same error?

I was trying to install Android Studio and Sdk files to use Flutter but I am not able to download the SDK files.

Comment: where's the error?

Comment: The error is that it doesn’t let me install sdk files and keeps showing the “preparing installation” screen

Comment: I solved the error by downloading the sdk files manully from home-brew